# Using user defined types in an array

Tags: vba, ms-access

It appears that it is not possible to create an empty and thus dynamic array of a user defined type.

I've tried several options provided by various 'help' websites including yours. I've spent the better part of a day researching dynamic arrays and user defined types.

```
Option Base 1
Public Type RegisteredItem
    ItemName as String
    ItemState as ItemStatus  ' an enum
End type

' note the 's'
' also tried (-1), but that must be very old stuff?
' also tried (16)

Dim RegisteredItems () as RegisteredItem

Public Function RegisterItem(aName as String, aState as ItemStatus) as integer

' now when RegisteredItems is used in code, instead of getting array properties, a choice of ItemName or ItemState is all that pops up.
```

`Debug.Print UBound(RegisteredItems)`  returns an error 13, type mismatch

basically, no array properties or methods seem to be available.

When I use `RegisteredItems.`, only `ItemName` and `ItemState` appear. It's as if there is no table.

as described in the code section. Would like to be able to use `Count` or `UBound = LBound` to see if the table is empty; would like to search the table if it's not empty and redim it to add new items when necessary, but currently, I must be missing something.

About me: I got out of the computer business in 1989. At that time when the dinos ran amuck, I knew 40 assembler languages and about 40 programming languages. I met Bill Gates and Steve Jobs when they can to view the XEROX PARC systems where I was working at the time. You can fill it in from there.

Answer (score 1):

You must either dimension the array when declared:

```vb
Dim RegisteredItems(4) As RegisteredItem
```

or, as will be the case for you, before using it:

```vb
Dim RegisteredItems() As RegisteredItem
' ...
ReDim RegisteredItems(7) As RegisteredItem
```

**Addendum**

This is what your module initially could look like:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Enum ItemStatus
    Active
    Passive
End Enum

Public Type RegisteredItem
    ItemName    As String
    ItemState   As ItemStatus
End Type

Public RegisteredItems() As RegisteredItem


' Add item.
'
Public Function RegisterItem(aName As String, aState As ItemStatus) As Integer

    Dim Item        As RegisteredItem
    Dim ItemCount   As Integer

    Item.ItemName = aName
    Item.ItemState = aState

    On Error Resume Next
    ItemCount = UBound(RegisteredItems)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ItemCount = ItemCount + 1

    ReDim Preserve RegisteredItems(ItemCount)
    RegisteredItems(ItemCount) = Item

    RegisterItem = ItemCount

End Function


' List items.
'
Public Sub ListRegisteredItems()

    Dim Index       As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    For Index = LBound(RegisteredItems) To UBound(RegisteredItems)
        Debug.Print Index, RegisteredItems(Index).ItemName, RegisteredItems(Index).ItemState
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So I tried "Dim RegisteredItems() as RegisteredItem"   and could not check to see if it was empty so I could then ReDim ..(1) when adding the first item and ReDim (n+1) for each additional item. Basically, I have tried declaring the array as an empty array and yet cannot access any properties or methods of the array. If I declare it as dimensioned, then I have access to the properties and methods that apply to arrays.

Comment: You must catch that error. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things. 
Checking for a empty array() requires error trapping
(this is unfortunate)

So, with this code:

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit

  Option Base 1

  Enum ItemStatus
    One = 1
    Two = 2
  End Enum


  Public Type RegisteredItem
      ItemName As String
      ItemState As ItemStatus  ' an enum
  End Type

  Sub Test22()

      Dim reg()        As RegisteredItem
      Dim intRows      As Integer

      On Error Resume Next
      intRows = UBound(reg)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         MsgBox "no rows in arrary"
      Else
         MsgBox "There are " & intRows & " in the array"
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0     ' turn error system back on

      ' add a row to the arrary
      intRows = intRows + 1
      ReDim Preserve reg(intRows)

      reg(intRows).ItemName = "Hello"
      reg(intRows).ItemState = One

  End Sub
```

Note how we have to test/check for the un-defined (empty) array.

Also, note that intel-sense will work for the enum. However, you don't go .ItemState.SomeEnum, but in fact assign the enum with = sign.

So this screen cap shows how the intel-sense will look for the enum of the array:
[image]

However you could consider creating a class module (a custom class).

Arrays go back to the "old" FORTRAN days, or say BASIC that was so often included with a PC in the DOS days.

However, collections are great, since you don't have to re-dim, there is a built in  "count" method. And they are dynamic.

So, you could create a class module like this:

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit

  ' Register class

  Public ItemName      As String
  Public Status        As ItemStatus
```

So, above was created as a class module, and saved as RegisterClass

Now, our code becomes far more simple:

```
  Sub Test22()

      Dim reg       As New RegisterClass
      Dim myCol     As New Collection


      reg.ItemName = "Hello"
      reg.Status = One

      Debug.Print "count in collection = " & myCol.Count
      myCol.Add reg

      Debug.Print "count in collection = " & myCol.Count

      'display one value
      Debug.Print myCol.Item(1).ItemName

      ' with above you don't  get intel sense
      ' but, you can go:

      Dim myValue   As RegisterClass

      For Each myValue In myCol
         Debug.Print myValue.ItemName
      Next


  End Sub
```

Comment: Collections solved the problem completed. Thanks Mr. Kallal for steering me in the right direction.